# How to generate GSONFormat for a property that can either be an object or string?

Tags: android, gson

I'm using GSON for parsing response from a Volley request and got stuck in creating a GSON format when the response has a property that can either be a string or an object or an array perhaps... e.g **`content`**

```
{
      "data": {
        "date_updated": "2016-12-21T03:55:29.955Z",
        "date_created": "2016-12-21T03:55:29.955Z",
        "content": "String here",
        "content": {
            "longitude": "",
            "latitude": ""
        },
        "status": "PROC",
        "_id": "5859fd31a93c7235575d62db"
      }
}
```

My current process in creating a GSON model is:

1. Create a java class
2. Right click and select Generate > GSONFormat
3. Paste the object I'm trying to convert then use it in Volley. 
   I tried the above object but it doesn't proceed. I think it's because of same property name.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I don't completely follow, but if the `content` property _might_ be an array, then just treat it as such.  Worst case scenario it would be empty, or maybe have only one element in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GsonFormat, you can look this:
https://github.com/zzz40500/GsonFormat

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure this answers my question. Yep, I am already using GSONFormat that way as mentioned in my statement. Try copy-pasting my data to your Android Studio to see what I mean. :)

Comment: And I think you json is uncorrect, I never see two property name.

Comment: yep that was my attempt as I'm experimenting how to deal response with multiple data types.... sometimes it's a string, sometimes an object. :p

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I know you question now . I can not come up with a way by now, maybe you should make two property name, one gives a string, other gives an object.

Comment: hmmm I'll post an answer here once I find a solution that works.