# How to fix plugins GsonFormat not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, gson

I downloaded the GsonFormat plugins and restart Android studio,

but when I want to generate data from Json, it still not working:(((

Please tell me how to fix it, thanks!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/poy0f.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOsL4.png)

Comment: did you try `alt + insert`?

Comment: @sagarsuri yes i try it, still not working

Comment: check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41255300/4161284

Comment: @sagarsuri same result :(((

Comment: @GuanHongHuang is there any solution?